# Animated film where space crew is being killed by zombies or a mysterious disease; used to be on Netflix

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

I remember watching an animated film on Netflix when I was a kid about a spaceship infested by a disease that turns people into zombies. It looked old and was removed from Netflix. It’s probably been around 11 years since I’ve last seen it. I keep on remembering it every now and then because of how it would scare me. It was definitely an adult rated film because of all the gore.

Comment: Hi, Kirizu! Welcome to the site. For some help improving this question, see [our great guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999).

Comment: (1) When did you see this movie? (We don’t know when you were a kid.) (2) Where were you at the time (what country)? (Yeah, I know you say Netflix, but they operate in nearly 200 countries.) (3) Was it in English? (4) Is it possible that the version you saw was dubbed (or had subtitles)? Do you know what language (and/or what country) it was made in? (5) Do you remember any characters in the movie? Any dialog? (6) You say “it looked old”. Can you be more specific? (Was it black and white?) … See also [our guidance](//scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/30482) on asking good story-ID questions.

Answer (score 7):

Was it "Dead Space: Downfall" (2008) perhaps?

An **alien artifact** is discovered in a remote colonized planet. A powerful corporation sends a ship to investigate based on religious beliefs only to find out  an **outbreak of violent behaviour** (I think they call it **massacre** several times).

The **ship gets infected** starting a race for survival with **very graphic** consequences.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Please can you [edit] your answer to add some explanation for how this film matches the OP's description?

Comment: Sorry, not used to this site :)

Comment: Also could have been Dead Space: Aftermath. +1 because this was what I thought immediately as well.